# Stop polybar from overlapping maximized windows in fluxbox

Tags: fluxbox

I am running `Fluxbox 1.3.7` and `polybar 3.5.7`

Whenever I maximize a window, polybar is overlapping the top of the window.
Is it possible to make windows treat polybar as a border? in other words, is it possible to get maximized windows to leave room for polybar?
I have tried `override-redirect = true` which simply makes the bar unmovable, but does not prevent it from overlapping maximized windows.
Also I don't believe the `wm-restack` option is applicable here as that only supports `i3` and `bspwm`

Thanks.